# Variable not passing to module

Tags: discord, discord.js

I can't get one of my variables to pass to the command modules.
Its declared at `const { token, ownerid, botid } = require('./config.json');` and passed through `command.execute(message, args, prefix, ownerid);` and read through `execute(message, args, prefix, ownerid) {` but when I try to log ownerid in the module, it turns up as undefined. Somewhere its getting erased I think. I tried logging it right before the command.execute and it reads it fine there, I think its getting lost on the way somehow.

Oh here is what ownerid should look like: `[ 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ]` (but with numbers obviously)
Anyone have any idea where my variable has gone to?

My temporary solution is to use fs to just read the file in the module instead of importing the variable.

Code: in order of use:

```js
const { token, ownerid, botid } = require('./config.json'); //declared

//command defined
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands');

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const commandfile = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(commandfile.name, commandfile);
    }
}

client.on('message', message => {
   //filters and stuff
   try {
        command.execute(message, args, prefix, ownerid);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

//in module
execute(message, args, prefix, ownerid) {
        for (let i = 0; i < ownerid.length; i++) {
            const dmme = message.client.users.cache.get(ownerid[i])
            const bugreportembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('New bug report!')
            .addField('Info', `From ${message.author.tag}`)
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .addField('Description', message.content.replace(`${prefix}bugreport `, ""))
            dmme.send(bugreportembed)
            message.channel.send('Sent!')
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with more of your code? You can also include the logs and mark where the variable is ok and where undefined. I personally don't see any problem. I think we need more context.

Comment: Sure! There you go!